# How can I remove or hide the page selection of pivot

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, uwp

Is there any way to edit style or some parameter that can change to hide/remove this part of the pivot?

[image]

I just want to remove the existing header of the pivot so I can do something that similar to this UI: [image: in my understanding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can edit the template to do that.

The pivot template is huge, scroll down to see this part:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ZoomMode="Disabled">
    <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid x:Name="PivotLayoutElement">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="PivotLayoutElementTranslateTransform"/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <!--......
            .. bla bla bla
            ......-->
        </Grid>
    </PivotPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

notice that the height of 1st `RowDefinition` is set to `auto`. Change it to 0 like this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

this will hide that header part.

But why do you want to do that? Without header, you can't navigate to one item to other, unless you wish to do that navigation programmatically for some reason. Also, take a look at [`FlipView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.FlipView), which I think the Control you might need.

Comment: I just want to make a menu like that one in Word Mobile. So I just hide the header of the pivot and use a combobox to select a page instead :D
Thanks for the answer. It really hard to find which item control what, in the hundreds line of template code.